# Add click event to dynamic button in xamarin

Tags: c#, events, button, xamarin, click

I want to add buttons from a list, depending of how many items there are in the list. It works perfectly when I do it like this:

[image]

The thing is they have no click events, I want each button to have an event that makes the user navigate to the right page depending on which button is clicked.

I'm trying to do it this way but it doesn't work:

[image]

Any ideas of the right way to do it if this is totally wrong?

Comment: define "doesn't works"

Comment: It says "; expected" but I don't think that's the problem. It would be embarrassing if I missed something like that, but I can't find where it should be placed if that's the case.

Comment: have you tried adding a ";" where the red squiggle is?

Comment: Yes I have. The message I get when I think the ";" is correctly placed is "Cannot convert from 'void' to 'Xamarin.Forms.View'".

Comment: Firstly, you should really never post images in place of thoughtfully typed out code. Secondly, where that red squiggle is, is definately where you want your ';' we likely need to see more of your code to determine why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the button before adding in to your `StackLayout`:

```
foreach(var item in question.Answers)
{
     var button = new Button();
     button.Text = item.AnswerText;
     button.Clicked += async delegate { await Navigation.PushAsync(item.NextPage); };

     stack.Children.Add(button);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this.

```
foreach(var item in question.Answers){

    var button = new Button{Text=item.AnswerText};
    button.Clicked += async(s,e)=> await Navigation.PushAsync(item.NextPage);
    stack.Children.Add(button);
}
```